# Add argument to all views without having to edit them all to include variable in Django

Tags: python, django

**What I need**

I'm developing a Pull Notification System to an existing Django Project. With there begin over 100+ views I'm looking to find a way to incorporate a argument(notification queryset) into all the views, as this is rendered to my base.html which I can do by passing it into a view's arguments dictionary.

**Problem**

I want to do this without editing all of the views as this would take a long time and would be required for all future views to include this variable.

**What I've tried**

Creating a template filter and pass in request.user as variable to return notification for that user. This works, however when the user selects a 'New' notification I want to send a signal back to the server to both redirect them to the notification link and change the status of viewed to 'True' (POST or AJAX). Which would required that specific view to know how to handle that particular request.

**What I've considered**

•   Editing the very core 'View' in Django.

I've tried my best to explain the issue, but if further info is required feel free to ask.

Thanks!

**models.py**

```py
class NotificationModel(models.Model):

    NOTIFICATION_TYPES = {'Red flag':'Red flag'}
    NOTIFICATION_TYPES = dict([(key, key) for key, value in NOTIFICATION_TYPES.items()]).items()

    notification_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPES, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py** Example

```py
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        notifications = NotificationsModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        args={'notifications':notifications}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def notification_handler(self, request)
        if 'notification_select' in request.POST:
            notification_id = request.POST['notification_id']
            notification = NotificationModel.objects.get(id=notification_id)
            notification.viewed = True
            notification.save()
            return redirect #some_url based on conditions

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        notifications = self.notification_handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if notifications:
            return notifications

        return self.get(self, request)
```

Comment: I don't get the problem, Perhaps some examples will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With there begin over 100+ views I'm looking to find a way to incorporate a argument(notification queryset) into all the views, as this is rendered to my base.html which I can do by passing it into a view's arguments dictionary.

You don't have to put it in the views (and actually, you shouldn't - views shouldn't have to deal with unrelated responsabilities) - you can just write a [simple custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) to fetch and render whatever you need in your base template. That's the proper "django-esque" solution FWIW as it leaves your views totally decoupled from this feature.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've done this already, however I wasn't aware it was the proper method of doing so. In terms of handling the responses, should I create a separate class in which all notification selection go to. Passing in the notification id through the url? Like ```python         url(r'^notification/(?P<notificationid>\d+)/$', views.NotificationRedirect.as_view(), name="notification_redirect"), ```

Comment: @LewisHepburn yep that's basically the idea - a custom tag for things that must be shown in all views and a specific view as endpoint to handle specific requests.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `mixins` ?

```
class NotificationMixin:
    my_var = 'whatever'
```

```
class MyDjangoView(NotificationMixin,.....,View)
    pass
```

Better, Using django builtins..

```
from django.views.generic import base

class NotificationMixin(base.ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['notification'] = 'whatever'    
        return context
```

and use this mixin with all your views *AS THE FIRST CLASS INHERITED*, See [this](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

For your case, Typing it instead of applying it to the base class is better, The base view class is not intended to be altered, It's meant to be extended, That's why we can solve the issue by this...

```
from django.generic.views import View as DjangoBaseView
from .mixins import NotificationMixin


class View(NotificationMixin, DjangoBaseView):
    pass
```

and use any IDE to change all the imported `View`s to your `View` and not the django one.

Comment: @ahmed-i-elsayed Thanks for your answer ahmed, but i'd need to apply this Mixin to all views. Could I apply it to the base class somehow? One which all my views inherit from. Also how would I handle post requests when a notification has been select. (Updated Question to include code)